# How can I use --gdk-debug with GTK2 programs?

Tags: 14.04, gtk, debugging, debug, gtk-2

I want to view the GDK events received by a GTK 2 program (Xournal) for debugging purposes, which should be possible by passing the option `--gdk-debug=events`). However, the option apparently is passed to the program directly, which understandably sees it as invalid (apparently it's supposed to be handled by GTK).

I haven't found any `-dbg` packages for GTK 2 (Ubuntu 14.04) that might make this option available - are there any at all? What I have installed is `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0-dbg` - no difference.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question: I had to build GTK 2 with the `--enable-debug` flag (`-dbg` packages only add symbols to debug the library itself) and preload the built GDK library. Steps:

- Run

  ```
  apt-get source gtk+2.0
  ```
- Enter the created `gtk+2.0<something>` directory
- In the `rules` file in the `debian` directory, add `--enable-debug=yes` to the `configure_flags`
- Run

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```
- Unpack the `libgtk2.0-0` Debian package with `dpkg -x <package> <directory>`, and descend into `/usr` until you see `.so` files
- Run the GTK2 program to be debugged with

  ```
  LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 <program>
  ```